Let G be a connected graph and let x,y∈V(G). Prove that if distance d(x, y)≥2, then there exists a vertex z∈V(G)\{x,y} such that d(x,y)=d(x,z)+d(z,y).
Let G be a connected graph and let x, y ∈ V(G). Prove that if distance d(x, y) ≥ 2, then there exists a vertex z ∈ V(G) \ {x, y} such that $d(x, y) = d(x, z) + d(z, y)$.
My progress until now:
Well I know that the distance of any two vertices in a graph is a metric (so it is symmetric, nonnegative and transitive), transitivity/or triangular inequality: $dist(x,y)<=dist(x,z)+dist(z,y)$, so I may find two approaches to prove this sixth question: either to show the inequality: $dist(x,y)>=dist(x,z)+dist(z,y)$ holds, or to directly show that $dist(x,y)=dist(x,z)+dist(z,y)$., well the distance between some vertices x and y is the length of the shortest path between these vertices (number of edges/not repeated), Is it true, that there exists a vertex z for which the equality $dist(x,y)=dist(x,z)+dist(z,y)$ holds, is on this shortest path between x and y (So the shortest path between x and y also contains a vertex z satysfying the equality)? Well if the distance dist(x,z) is a length of some shortest path between x and z, which is internally disjunct path with the segment of the path x-y between the vertices x and z, then there would be shorter path between x and y, so we would get contradiction with assumption that we had the shortest path between x and y, and same for the vertices z and y, am I right ?

Hi, welome to math-se! Please, use math-jax to write your answer.

for any vertex $z$ that lies on the shortest path between $x$ and $y$ we have the desired equality

Yes, every vertex $z$ on every shortest path between $x$ and $y$ will satisfy $d(x,y) = d(x,z) + d(z,y)$, and you can prove this as you wrote, by contradiction.
Note that the assumption $d(x,y)\geq 2$ implies that a shortest path has at least one internal vertex (a vertex other than $x$ and $y$), so such a $z$ exists.
Side remark: the converse is true too: if $x,y,z$ satisfy $d(x,y) = d(x,z) + d(z,y)$, then there is a shortest path between $x$ and $y$ containing $z$ (proof: take a shortest $x-z$ path and a shortest $z-y$ path and prove that together they form a shortest $x-y$ path).
The set of such vertices $z$ is sometimes called the interval $I(x,y)$.

So the contradiction which I used is correct ?

Essentially yes. More formally: let P be a shortest x-y path (so P has length d(x,y)), let z be any internal vertex, let R be the fragment of P between x and z, let Q be the fragment between z and y. Clearly len(P)=len(R)+len(Q). We claim R is a shortest x-z path, that is, len(R) = d(x,z). Proof by contradiction: if there was any shorter x-z path (no matter if it is internally disjoint or not), then together with Q it would make a shorter x-y path. Similarly you prove len(Q)=d(z,y). Hence d(x,y)=len(P)=len(R)+len(Q)=d(x,z)+d(z,y).

(One minor technical detail: the shorter x-z path together with the z-y path Q does not necessarily form a path, since it might have self-intersections; we can say it is a walk. But by removing any fragments between self-intersections from a walk we get a path, and it can only get shorter).

Alternatively, to avoid talking about disjointness or self-intersecting walks, you can say $d(x,z) \leq len(R)$, because $R$ is a path beween $x$ and $z$. Similarly $d(z,y) \leq len(Q)$. So altogether $d(x,y) = len(P)= len(R)+len(Q) \geq d(x,z) + d(z,y)$, which is the direction we wanted to prove.
